# Token сайта, как правильно получить/спарсить?

Tags: javascript, php, token

Всем доброго времени суток!
На сайте платежного шлюза при запросе расчета комиссии отправление с карты на карту, отправляются следующие данные: sPan, rPan, amount и собственно говоря токен. Вопрос в следующем, каким образом его можно получить/сгенерировать и тд. Попробовал поискать в коде страницы, но там совершено другой токен. Заранее извинюсь за глупый вопрос, если он таковым покажется.
P.S Скриншоты для наглядности:
Токен в коде страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Токен в запросе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы отправите ссылку на сайт, то получите ответ на свой ответ намного быстрее.

Comment: Весьма логично, что вы увидели два разных токена, ведь это было два разных подключения. Подумайте, как сервер узнает, что отправил вам именно этот токен? Я думаю, что используются сессии: подключаетесь [отправляете `phpsessid`] - сервер [генерирует токен, сохраняет его в сессии] отправляет токен. Считаю, нужно сохранить `phpsessid`, чтобы сервер знал, кто отправил токен и с чем его сравнивать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во вкладке Initator ( чуть правее Headers, которая на скрине ) есть стек скриптов, придеться используя breakpoints или logpoint пройти до места где генерируеться этот токен, но путь этот может быть тернист и сложен =)

Сам токен может быть создан как угодно и для чего угодно, сервер может кстати и проигнорировать его отсутсвие или правильность, поэтому для начала стоит убедиться в  его необходимости.

Возможно токен с первого скрина верный, сервер может генерировать новый токен каждый раз когда отдает страницу, т.е. если первый и второй скрин относяться к разным запросам, тогда нормально, что они разные.

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ, да, запрос можно послать и без токена, но он необходим для других запросов, просто было интересно узнать как он создается. Буду разбираться в вашем ответе

Comment: Дополню. При загрузке страницы, в коде значится токен на первом скрине, но при запросе «комиссии» , используется уже другой токен, тот же, что при всех последующих запросах, видимо гипотеза, о новом токене на каждый запрос тут не сработает(